# didSelectRowAtIndexPath Segue Not Sending

Tags: swift, swift2, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, appdelegate

**UPDATED QUESTION**

The code in the AppDelegate in my app crashes/doensn't recognize the segue when segueing in the MainStoryBoard when the code below is active.

In my AppDelegate I'm adding the following lines of code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to set the header. However, I can't remove the code or else I won't have a header, and unfortunately it requires it to be the rootViewController. Any suggestions how to rephrase this? :

```
   var tableVC:FeedTableViewController = FeedTableViewController(className: "ProductInfo")

        let headerImage = UIImage(named:"header.png")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(headerImage, forBarMetrics:.Default)
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default

        var navigationVC:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tableVC)



       let frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        window = UIWindow(frame: frame)

        window!.rootViewController = navigationVC
       window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

When I take out the `window` code that defines the rootVC, etc. I am able to segue without a problem. My header that I set in the appDelegate also disappears.

The error i get on the crash is that the receiver VC does not have a segue called "mySegue". The receiver VC is supposed to be my initial VC and is set as the initial VC in the Storyboard.

The segue is being performed on didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Why is that? Any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you instantiating, dequeuing and loading nib of that cell in the delegate method in the first place?

Comment: Started to just try everything. Tried without it and it was crashing, now that I have it it doesn't crash but it doesn't work. Doesn't make sense...

Comment: You have the indexPath, differentiate between cells based on that.

Comment: Error is: `reason: 'Receiver (<Attempt2.FeedTableViewController: 0x7fb52bea1da0>) has no segue with identifier 'sender''`

Comment: Your segue does not have that identifier named sender. Use the correct identifier. And read documentation on how to use tableview instead of trying everything. Also read about segues.

Comment: When i use Instantiate it gives an error for an optional value.

Comment: I added the identifier. It can't find it apparently.

Comment: Click on segue between your Two VCs. In Right hand pane, you will get the  option to add its identifier.Like this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/XDUoT.png And try giving it a meaningful name instead of sender. And DONT do anything with the cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` unless you need it to perform some action

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94807/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-nsnoob).

Comment: You are not using prepareForSegue correctly either. Seriously mate, find a tutorial. It will take ages to teach you all about it here. PrepareForSegue is called from the sourceViewController, not Destination one. The segue named `sender` is from source to dest, not the other way around. Dest has no such segue and yet you are making it perform it. Thats why you are getting that error. FeedTableViewController must be your destinationVC, I assume?

Comment: You don't understand. I'm pushing from the FeedTableViewController to the other ViewController. I've used both methods dozens of times. For some reason its not working now, that's the issue so I'm trying all sorts of methods to see what triggers it.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. The dequeuing is only for creating cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. To get the cell once created, use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you just need to call `performSegue`.

In prepare for segue, you can use the `indexPath` to inform the destination controller of any data it needs to know.

Better: drag the segue not from the controller symbol but from the cell itself. You then do not need the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at all but can handle all the logic in `prepareForSegue`.

The `sender` will then be the cell and you can get the indexPath with `tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)`.

Comment: Just added in my answer that I'm already using the prepareForSegue. Can you give me the line of code needed for the `prepareForSegue` method, specifically for indexPath? Im having a hard time understanding how to use the indexPath in the method.

Comment: The index path can give you access to your data model. You did not tell us anything about your data model. In case you are confused, study the [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) (Model View Controller) pattern.